# Tor gets stuck on "Loading Network Status"

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

This is the Log I get after clicking:

```
Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/12/19, 17:45:37.240 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/12/19, 17:45:37.240 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/12/19, 17:45:37.240 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/12/19, 17:45:37.853 [WARN] Managed proxy at 'TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\terminateprocess-buffer.exe' reported: 2019/07/12 17:45:37 running firefox command ["C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe" "--invisible" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.meek-http-helper"] 
7/12/19, 17:45:37.853 [WARN] Managed proxy at 'TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\terminateprocess-buffer.exe' reported: 2019/07/12 17:45:37 firefox started with pid 2156 
7/12/19, 17:45:38.867 [WARN] Managed proxy at 'TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\terminateprocess-buffer.exe' reported: 2019/07/12 17:45:38 running meek-client command ["TorBrowser\\Tor\\PluggableTransports\\meek-client.exe" "--helper" "127.0.0.1:64639"] 
7/12/19, 17:45:38.867 [WARN] Managed proxy at 'TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\terminateprocess-buffer.exe' reported: 2019/07/12 17:45:38 meek-client started with pid 2600 
7/12/19, 17:45:38.868 [WARN] Managed proxy at 'TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\terminateprocess-buffer.exe' reported: 2019/07/12 17:45:38 using helper on 127.0.0.1:64639 
7/12/19, 17:45:38.868 [WARN] Managed proxy at 'TorBrowser\Tor\PluggableTransports\terminateprocess-buffer.exe' reported: 2019/07/12 17:45:38 listening on 127.0.0.1:64640 
7/12/19, 17:45:38.869 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 1% (conn_pt): Connecting to pluggable transport 
7/12/19, 17:45:38.888 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 2% (conn_done_pt): Connected to pluggable transport 
7/12/19, 17:45:38.890 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay 
7/12/19, 17:45:45.944 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay 
7/12/19, 17:45:50.732 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15% (handshake_done): Handshake with a relay done 
7/12/19, 17:45:50.733 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20% (onehop_create): Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
7/12/19, 17:45:53.950 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25% (requesting_status): Asking for networkstatus consensus 
7/12/19, 17:45:54.174 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges 
7/12/19, 17:46:03.240 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 30% (loading_status): Loading networkstatus consensus 
7/12/19, 17:46:03.360 [NOTICE] new bridge descriptor 'cymrubridge02' (fresh): $97700DFE9F483596DDA6264C4D7DF7641E1E39CE~cymrubridge02 at 0.0.2.0 
7/12/19, 17:46:26.360 [WARN] Refusing to apply consensus diff because the base consensus doesn't match the digest as found in the consensus diff header. 
7/12/19, 17:46:26.360 [WARN] Expected: 31A519B72EC64D5CFC5340E47D34F15B815674E6833F447C344C0F34F66D1B69; found: A7967A9A0A73D3197EA6A9DADAC9667918E4BE4A49AF56E19317FB1AD0255648 
7/12/19, 17:46:26.361 [WARN] Could not apply consensus diff received from server '0.0.2.0:2' 
7/12/19, 17:47:25.190 [WARN] Refusing to apply consensus diff because the base consensus doesn't match the digest as found in the consensus diff header. 
7/12/19, 17:47:25.190 [WARN] Expected: 31A519B72EC64D5CFC5340E47D34F15B815674E6833F447C344C0F34F66D1B69; found: A7967A9A0A73D3197EA6A9DADAC9667918E4BE4A49AF56E19317FB1AD0255648 
7/12/19, 17:47:25.191 [WARN] Could not apply consensus diff received from server '0.0.2.0:2' 
7/12/19, 17:47:25.191 [WARN] Refusing to apply consensus diff because the base consensus doesn't match the digest as found in the consensus diff header. 
7/12/19, 17:47:25.191 [WARN] Expected: 31A519B72EC64D5CFC5340E47D34F15B815674E6833F447C344C0F34F66D1B69; found: A7967A9A0A73D3197EA6A9DADAC9667918E4BE4A49AF56E19317FB1AD0255648 
7/12/19, 17:47:25.191 [WARN] Could not apply consensus diff received from server '0.0.2.0:2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be to use a bridge. If you are trying to connect at at a workplace or at an University, then Tor is probably being blocked.

[image]